# jagged fonts rendering after using filter:FlipH in IE only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

I am rendering text in the reverse, the below code works like a champ. The issue is IE, the fonts are all rendered with VERY jagged edges. Anyone have a suggestion as to how to make it render properly in IE?

```
.flipText {
display: block;
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Gecko */
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Opera */
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* webkit */
    transform: scaleX(-1); /* standard */
    filter: FlipH; /* IE 6/7/8 */
-ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Comment: I solved this by adding  style="background-color:#fff;" to the el that contained the actual text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a background-color the elements containing the actual text, I was able to "mask" the effect being rendered in IE. ()..

Answer (score 0):

You can make it look good in IE9 (and higher) by adding `-ms-transform: scaleX(-1);` and restricting the filters to IE8 and lower (with a conditional comment, for example):

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ATsbe/3/

As far as I know, there's no way to make the text look good in IE8 and lower.